# Android command line tools Panic Android_SDK_root broken

Tags: android, android-emulator

For our QA team we need to provide an Android emulator without Android Studio.To do this I used the line tools command provided by Google.

I made this folder tree

```
kit-emulator
 -android-sdk
 -avd
```

in the android-sdk subfolder I put the line tools command folder and from this folder using the sdkmanager I download the sdk with this command

```
sdkmanager --sdk_root=C:\Users\EBERTGU\Desktop\kit-emulator\android-sdk platform-tools emulator platforms;android-30 system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64
```

The download goes smoothly.

The avd folder is designed to accommodate the newly created emulator. For that I use the avdmanager of command line tools with the following command

```
avdmanager create avd -n "a350" -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64" -p "C:\Users\EBERTGU\Desktop\kit-emulator\avd\a350" -f -d "pixel_4_xl"
```

The emulator is created in the a350 folder contained in the avd folder. You may be wondering what's wrong then. It's s the launch of the emulator.

When I start the emulator with the command emulator @350 I have this error

```
PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

Error which is explained by itself. So I set my environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to  `C:\Users\EBERTGU\Desktop\kit-emulator\android-sdk`

I restart the commande line prompt and start again to start the emulator this time I got this error

```
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Users\EBERTGU\Desktop\kit-emulator\android-sdk]!
```

Now I don't understand why it doesn't work. I searched and opened the emulator ini file inside I found the line

```
image.sysdir.1=android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86_64\
```

In despair I changed it to

```
image.sysdir.1=C:\Users\EBERTGU\Desktop\kit-emulator\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86_64\
```

And when I try to start the emulator with the modified image.sysdir.1 line it works !

Anyone have an explanation of why launching doesn't work with base value for image.sysdir.1 and environment variable?

Thank you a lot

Have a nice day

Shindra Guillaume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was the generation of the emulator from the avdmanager in the bin folder of command tools lines. Just put the files at the root of command tools lines in a subfolder and the system image is properly configured to match that of the root SDK